# Progress bar never shows

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-view

Caveat: I am a bit of a neophyte on Android, working with someone else's code.

The app I'm working with does a long background process and currently appears to just "hang" while it's working.

I just want to show a progress bar while it's working.  The process is not on the main thread, but the flow of the thread that invokes the process needs to go like this:

1. Show progress bar
2. Call function that does huge processing and returns when done (and updates progress bar)
3. Hide progress bar

This is the function I came up with:

```
int mProgressMax = 0;
ProgressBar mProgressBar = null;
void ShowProgressBar() {
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(mActivity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
        mProgressBar.setMax(mProgressMax);
        ViewGroup rootView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        rootView.addView(mProgressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });
}
```

I do not have any kind of "layout" for the progress bar because the app creates all its layouts programmatically.  So I also have to create it programmatically, since I don't have permission to restructure anything.

As it stands, I never see the progress bar.  I get no errors or anything, it just never shows.

What do I need to add to make this work?

Extra Info: The thread that does the long processing is invoked via an intent where the user had to pick the file.  I think this intent might be covering the progress bar, but I don't know how to get the progress bar on top of it.

This is how that intent is invoked:

```
public void OpenFilePicker(Uri uriToLoad, int theCode) {
    Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    aIntent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
    aIntent.putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
    //aIntent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(aIntent, theCode);
}
```

...and then the onActivityResult is where the long process (including the progress bar show) happens.